# How do I do .find in MYSQL Select?

Tags: mysql, database

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE column1.find("has_this_word_somewhere") ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You use LIKE

> DELETE FROM table where column LIKE '%SOMETHING%';

Comment: Don't use double quotes to delimit SQL string literals. They are an invention of the devil.

Answer (score 1):

isn't this just the same as `where column like '%has_this_word_somewhere%'`